# Alternative Proof of Riesz Representation Theorem on R

Tags: linear-algebra

I don’t understand how the following proof is an equivalent to the Riesz Representation Theorem on real numbers.

Let $Tu$ denote the linear functional on V defined by $(Tu)(v)=<v,u>$ for $v \in V$.

1. Show that $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V’$ on the real numbers
2. Show that $T$ is injective and thus invertible
3. Show that $T$ is an isomorphism from $V$ onto $V’$ on the real numbers

I dont have trouble proving all 3 statements but I don’t quite understand how showing T is an isomorphism is equivalent to the Riesz Representation Theorem on real numbers. Hoping anyone here could guide me

Comment: Regarding the question of equivalence: one you have such a map $T$, it follows that for any functional $\varphi \in V'$, $T^{-1}(\varphi) \in V$ is the unique Riesz representation of $\varphi$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks alot for the help, it makes much more sense now,